# check file's LastWriteTime is yesterday by SYSTEMTIME

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to check lots of files which the LastWriteTimes are the same as the date of the system's yesterday or not. My question is how to set the date-time of yesterday in the SYSTEMTIME format.
The following is my code.

```
    bool checkLastWriteTime(FILETIME ftLastWriteTime)
    {
        SYSTEMTIME stUTC, stLocal;
        // Convert the last-write time to local time.
        FileTimeToSystemTime(&ftLastWriteTime, &stUTC);
        SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime(NULL, &stUTC, &stLocal);

        // Build a string showing the date and time.
        _tprintf(TEXT("%02d/%02d/%d  %02d:%02d\n"),
            stLocal.wMonth, stLocal.wDay, stLocal.wYear,
            stLocal.wHour, stLocal.wMinute);

        SYSTEMTIME localTime;
        GetLocalTime(&localTime);

      //
      //How to get the date of yesterday from localTime?
      //

        if (stLocal.wYear == localTime.wYear && stLocal.wMonth == localTime.wMonth && stLocal.wDay == localTime.wDay)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Yesterday" is a *range*.  It is pretty easy to calculate when it ended, that happened at 12 am this morning:

```
SYSTEMTIME now;
GetLocalTime(&now);
SYSTEMTIME stYesterdayEnd = { now.wYear, now.wMonth, now.wDayOfWeek, now.wDay };
FILETIME ftYesterdayEnd;
SystemTimeToFileTime(&stYesterdayEnd, &ftYesterdayEnd);
```

It started 24 hours before that.  So you need to subtract as many 100 nanosecond units from ftYesterdayEnd.  A bit tricky with FILETIME, we'll use a LARGE_INTEGER to make it easy:

```
LARGE_INTEGER liYesterdayBeg = { ftYesterdayEnd.dwLowDateTime, ftYesterdayEnd.dwHighDateTime };
ULONGLONG oneday = 24ULL * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 1000 * 10;
liYesterdayBeg.QuadPart -= oneday;
FILETIME ftYesterdayBeg = { liYesterdayBeg.LowPart, liYesterdayBeg.HighPart };
```

Now you're set to write your function:

```
bool wasWrittenYesterday(FILETIME ftLastWriteTime)
{
    // As above
    //...
    return ftLastWriteTime >= ftYesterdayBeg && ftLastWriteTime < ftYesterdayEnd
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert SYSTEMTIME to FILETIME, then subtract the day and reconvert to SYSTEMTIME.

Something like this:

```
FILETIME ft;
ULARGE_INTEGER uli;
__int64 oneDay;

GetLocalTime(&localTime);
SystemTimeToFileTime(&localTime, &ft);
memcpy(&uli, (ULARGE_INTEGER *)&ft, sizeof(ULARGE_INTEGER));

// get one day in 100ns parts
oneDay = (__int64)10 * (__int64)1000 * (__int64)1000;
oneDay *= (__int64)60 * (__int64)60 * (__int64)24;

// subtract one day 
uli.QuadPart -= oneDay;

FileTimeToSystemTime((LPFILETIME)&uli, &localTime);
```

After running this code *localTime* contains *now* minus 24 hours.

See also Remarks within [SYSTEMTIME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms724950(v=vs.85).aspx) reference